# Why can not I access many telegram groups? And it shows "There is no Telegram account with the username you provided." error

Tags: telegram

As an example, I know this account exists "https://t.me/everexio" but when I click view, it fails with *"There is no Telegram account with the username you provided."* 
**I have seen this issue many times and with different groups**.
And I know that it is not only my problem.
Tying mobile app, desktop app, or web base program without success.

**edit**

A lot of global projects, companies and organizations are using this app to communicate with their audience, if this kind of restrictions exist then their group is not available everywhere and by using it as a main tool they won't be able to connect all of their community members.

So it is important for both parties to know clearly about this restrictions.

Comment: This is sad story ... https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/7448qg/telegram_show_no_account_with_username_on_some/#ampf=undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your problem, it's all Iranians problem(At least). Telegram servers didn't allow Iranian Phone number to join this groups. You can join to this groups using a (not Iranian) virtual number while your VPN is turned on.

Comment: how could I create a virtual number?
is it free? e.g. https://tollfreeforwarding.com?

Comment: You can search `free virtual number for telegram` in Google.Also there are some android applications which create virtual numbers. But unfortunately most of virtual numbers are banned by telegram.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe temporary banned this function of Telegram, check [@SpamBot](https://t.me/SpamBot) for your status and more information.

If @SpamBot say you are free, contact support team, them should have permission to help you.

> Please contact in-app Support if you have more questions (Settings — Ask a question).
>   Notice that we rely on volunteers support in Telegram
>   (so please be nice).

Comment: Bot says I am free, do I try support.

Answer (score -1):

Iranians cannot join telegram group with short link by their own phone number. We are banned from inside and restricted from outside. Hope Telegram team remove this restriction or at least explain why they did this to us.https://twitter.com/yoosofan/status/1001923754950381569. If you are in Iran you can test it by clicking on https://t.me/publictestgroup which is the official group of telegram represented in https://telegram.org/faq#q-what-makes-telegram-groups-cool.

If you have any doubt about this, you can easily get an mobile phone number from Iran (starting with 98 9) and create a telegram account on it. Then try to join groups like [@PangeaBitnation](https://t.me/PangeaBitnation), you will not able to join them. You cannot even find them by search on your telegram application.
I checked it by my own Irancell phone number (starting by 98 938).

Comment: I am not sure that this restriction is only for one special country

Comment: I am totally sure. It is tested by me and several other Iranians.